# GoogleHomeでテレビをミュート（消音）する方法について

Tags: google-cloud

テレビへ音量をミュートにする信号を送るデバイスとのGoogleHome連携機能の開発を試みております。
VolumeのvolumeCanMuteAndUnmuteにTrueを設定しておりますが、
実際に「テレビをミュートにして」と発話しても「デバイスが見つかりません。」とエラーになります。
action.devices.commands.muteコマンドも呼び出されません。
ミュート機能を実装するために必要な処理はございますでしょうか。